# How to update page url on page refresh?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, jquery

I am looking for a way to change page url (change one of the url key's value) when the user refreshes the page. I am doing this to reflect changes on the contents of the page. I have tried several methods but they all have a loop problem. Below is one of the methods:

In my html page:

```html
<body onLoad="CheckPageLoad();">
    <input type="hidden" name="trial" id="trial" value="hello" />
</body>
```

In the page.asp page: (*inside a script tag*)

```js
function CheckPageLoad() {
    if ($("#trial").val() == "hello") {
        // This is a fresh page load
        alert('Load');
        $("#trial").val("hi");
    } else {
        // This is a page refresh
        window.location = url;
        alert('Refresh');
    }
}
```

**Issues**:

1. Every time the page is refreshed, the Load alert is always displayed. I thought the load is done once. It looks like every time the page is refreshed, it reloads so the value always remains  to be hello.
2. I tried using the script tag only and the new url is opened but keeps looping. (This is the main problem)

Any suggestion to update the above method or use another method to do the refresh is appreciated. Below are other methods I also tried:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = unloadPage();

function unloadPage() {
    //do something
    //works but loops
}
```

Thanks

Comment: window.location triggers a page refresh so your hello variable is reset. You could try using a session to store that 'hello' 'idea'.

Comment: "_It looks like every time the page is refreshed, it reloads_" Yes, that's the way it works.

Comment: So how shall I open the new url and stop the loop? It opens the new url and that one will open another url and this keeps going on. The new url is the same page with only one key's value in the url changed. Example: url1 http://www.aaaa.com/?element=1&pool=5 and url2 is http://www.aaaa.com/?element=1&pool=6.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). We could probably offer better help if you gave us some context on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Silvermind - can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

I put the following code into a basic page and it demonstrates why you are getting the described behaviour:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CheckPageLoad() {
                if ($("#trial").val() == "hello") {
                    // This is a fresh page load
                    alert('Load');
                    $("#trial").val("hi");
                } else {
                    // This is a page refresh
                    alert('Refresh');
                    window.location = window.location + '?id=1';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="CheckPageLoad();">
        <input type="hidden" name="trial" id="trial" value="hello" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When you set the window.location it changes the url (well duh!) which therefore means you are loading a new page. When the page is refreshed you get a "Refresh" alert before a "Load". This demonstrates that the page is posting back first, but the onload event causes the page to navigate to another location, therefore loading it again. It is my understanding that updating anything in the URL ultimately is a new request/newly loaded page.

You might find the following useful regarding the viewstate in asp (seeing as you suggested you are using an asp page): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

My suggestion would be to completely remove the `window.location = url;` part of your code in favour of looking at the data which was posted back instead. This means that you aren't unnecessarily loading the page twice on postback and allows you to access the data from any updated inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I am checking the links you suggested. If I remove window.location=url2, what other suggestion do you have to open url2.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this issue. The alerts are only for debugging. Load alert always shows every time the page is refreshed. Refresh alert is not working. It looks like every time the page is refreshed, the value remains hello.???

Comment: If you save the above code as a html file you'll find the Refresh alert is actually displayed, in your code you navigate away from the page before you can run it. And as stated above assigning a new value to window.location will cause the page to be reloaded rather than refreshed. Why do you need to change the URL on postback?

Comment: That is to open a new url - the new url is almost the same as the old url except one of the old url key gets a new value in the new url.

Comment: Then you will be loading each time, the setting of `window.location` means you are loading a new page (loading the new url) as opposed to refreshing the page. What you should be doing is not depending on a hidden field to determine if something has been posted back to as this hidden field will be loaded as if new each time the page is navigated to (not posted back to).

Comment: That is exactly what is happening. I have started using a different approach to do the refresh.